# Drupal webform submission - Comments, like

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-webform

We have an small internal webform setup within the business that currently collects ideas for the business submitted by users which are emailed off to single email inbox. This has been in place for a while now and has generated 100's of submissions.

The business would like to encourage more user interactivity by:

- Allowing users to see all submissions (after they've been confirmed by the admin, perhaps pulled in via a view or into individual nodes)
- Allowing anonymous users to comment on each webform submission
- Allowing anonymous users to like a submission via a button

Currently it does the job perfectly well as a webform and has a lot of submissions, but not sure if webforms are flexible enough to allow the new functionality the business wants.

Thoughts were if there was a way to turn all submissions into nodes then create a view to pull in all these nodes, which would then allow commenting etc...

Could anyone suggest a best way of approaching this or what modules might work for this?

Answer (score 0):

My first thoughts are create a content type with the same fields as your webform.

Then create a feed and feed importer to import the webform submissions as nodes.

You will need the following modules and dependencies:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export
- https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds
- https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex

With views data export you can create an XML feed

Feeds and Feeds extensible parsers will allow you to import the XML feed with XPath.

To allow submissions to be moderated, I would recommend:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench
- https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation

You can use these modules to have a nice workflow of draft -> needs review -> published. This will store a revision of each edit also.

Drupal has comments built in, you may need to enable the comment module, you can also set these up so they have to be moderated first, please be advised this may require a fulltime website moderator. You could use a flag (https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) such as report as offensive instead allowing users to flag inappropriate comments for removal. A view could then be made showing all comments that have been flagged. Using a module such as VBO (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) will allow you to delete multiple comments at a time.

A like button can be achieved with flags there is a module (https://www.drupal.org/project/dlike) however it would be just as easy to create your own flag.

If you would like any further help/further explaination please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. Will let you know how it turns out / if I get stuck. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a follow up to this. 

What I have got so far is I have kept the webform and have setup a rule that creates a new entity of a new content type I have created. This is set as unpublished by default (which was a requirement to only display once moderated) and can be amended / deleted also. These new nodes also allow comments and have sorted it so anonymous comments are available. All of which are pulled into a view for display.

Still a bit of work to do with it, but just thought I'd update. Thanks again for the recommendations / help.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could mark my answer as the accepted answer if you are happy with it